# Flutter - Function - Return Array

Tags: flutter, return-value

I've build an List with 44 places:

```
List<String> departmentdes = new List(44);
```

after that I've called a function:

```
postDepartment();
```

The function is an api call:

```
postDepartment() async {
    final response = await http.get('url');
    final jsonresponse = json.decode(response.body);

    List<Department> departments = [];

    for(var d in jsonresponse) {
      Department department = Department(
        fid: d["fid"].toString(),
      );
      departments.add(department);
    }
    int index = departments.length -1;

     for(int i = 0; i<=index; i++) {
      departmentdes[i] = departments[i].fid;
    } 
    return departmentdes;
  }
```

After the `postDepartment();` I want to print the departmentdes but it always returns null. Why?

Comment: it seems to me you have a typo in the line where you return

Comment: `await postDepartment()`

Answer (score 0):

i < index

You're already defining index to be length -1

Just a little logic error.

Comment: This wouldn't explain why the function returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `postDepartment` to this and see if it helps:

```
Future<void> postDepartment() async {
  final response = await http.get('url');
  final jsonresponse = json.decode(response.body);

  List<Department> departments = [];

  for(var d in jsonresponse) {
   Department department = Department(
     fid: d["fid"].toString(),
   );
   departments.add(department);
  }
  int index = departments.length -1;

  for(int i = 0; i<=index; i++) {
   departmentdes[i] = departments[i].fid;
  } 
  return departmentdes;
}
```

Also check if your `departments` is not null.